# How can I download HP-UX 11i v1/v2/v3 iso or vmware file?

Tags: vmware, hp-ux

I want to some test on HP-UX 11i v1/v2/v3.But I cant find any download link or information. Please help me about this because I ve searched for more than 3 hours? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a commercial product. You can't legally download it without a license. So contact HP.